# Zend Framework 2 urlencode

Tags: php, zend-framework2, urlencode

I want to convert string to string which are url friendly

In my none Zend Framework 2 project is just use urlencode($valueContainingString);

Now i'm building an application with Zend Framework 2, now I was wondering if there is any better way to do this.

I did some research and I looked at constrains for the route but it's not working for me.

Comment: is urlencode() not working for you? I use rawurlencode() in ZF2 project which should work the same and url friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `\Zend\Escaper` classes - there you have plenty of escaping functions for most common use cases.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html

Comment: Thanks, that will do trick for now. It's not perfect for SEO but that's something for later

Comment: SEOing your URLs is not part of escaping, but a step before escaping. You'd usually reduce the number of allowed characters, lowercase everything and replace spaces with dashes. But this step is part of your URL-creation logic, and not part of escaping. Even if you did SEO your URLs, you'd have to escape.